# Custom Password field on Employee Record

Tags: netsuite

We have built an integration between Netsuite and our external system. We want to store the external system's credentials on the employee record but I'm having a really difficult time understanding how the password field type is supposed to work.

The documentation states "When validating, you pull the encrypted password value into a hidden field and use custom code to encrypt the value the user typed and compare it with the actual encrypted value."

But aside from this I don't feel like I have a solid idea on what the proper implementation should be.

Comment: there is no mention on which encryption algo to use, and what would be the key. Also, when you try to read value it gives "(Encrypted)" not the encrypted string

Comment: which has pretty much been my issue, the documentation provided is inadequate to implement with any certainty. Mainly, I want to make sure our implementation follows Netsuite / security best practices but it seems this instance may be a bit of a gray area.

Comment: for my use case, I was encrypting on own and then storing the values on a plain free-form text field. The encryption key was locked/hidden in my code as my code went into client machine as managed bundle. You can take this approach as an alternate solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

So essentially I ended up doing what prasun did. One thing I did do what still create a password type field and add a client script on record save to encrypt the entered password and insert the value into another plain text field that was not displayed on the UI. This had the desired user experience to fulfill my requirements (showing the standard password field). From there, we just decrypted the encrypted field (the one we copied our password into and encrypted) during run time. So it's a little bit of a round about trip but it is working and in no place is the password being stored in plain text which was our desired goal!

Comment: if you are encrypting/decrypting on the client side it takes away the purpose as anyone can see the source code on client side and take the secret key. I suggest you to let the password go on server side as plain text (it goes through https, so, its secured on wire), and do encryption on server side.

Comment: Shouldn't password hash be one way? Decryption should not be possible right?

Comment: So you're running your own encryption on the client side, then decrypting on the server side, then encrypting again on the server side to compare to the netsuite encryption? I'm not sure encryption on the client side is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

or you can create a password fiels in plain text and can hide that field.The security level is low but still we can implement it with less effort.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. It only introduces a dangerously insecure scheme.